# Dynamically compile service and include dll reference from another folder

Tags: c#, wcf, dynamically-generated

I have library along this path:

> "..\ServiceGenerator\bin\Debug\ExternalClassLibrary.dll"

ServiceGenerator project dynamically generates services from text and includes reference to this library.

```
objCompilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase + "ExternalClassLibrary.dll");
```

ServiceGenerator put services to this folder:

> "..\ServiceGenerator\bin\Debug\Services\"

And if I don't put ExternalClassLibrary.dll to this folder and then generate service, the method, which uses ExternalClassLibrary.dll, freezes.
If I put library in

> "..\ServiceGenerator\bin\Debug\Services\"

then all works fine.

How can I make a generated service work with the library from the path?

> "..\ServiceGenerator\bin\Debug\ExternalClassLibrary.dll"

Comment: It looks like you may be able to use the probing section of an assembly binding redirect: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4191fzwb(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I put app.config to services folder with probing element.
Set privatePath="..\". It doesn't work.

Comment: That should be another question - if you post the link back here I'll have a look at it

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: I mean you should post a new question to ask about the specific problem you are having configuring probing

Comment: Now I have your idea. Thank you =)